# UITableview sticky header not properly rendered on iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I've got a sticky header in the UITableView, which works well on all devices, except on the iPhone X. On there the top margin (-24) won't be initiated on first render, only when I start scrolling it snaps into place like it should.

Here is the example:
[image: Green is the background of the tableview]

Here's the code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: headerId) as! ArticleDetailHeader

    header.article = article
    headerView = header

    return header
}
```

This loads after the header is displayed

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    updateHeaderView()
}
```

This is the updateHeaderView function

```
    func updateHeaderView() {

        var height = CGFloat(460)

        if ((view.frame.width * 0.56) < 459) {
            height = view.frame.width * 0.56
        }

        let offsetY = tableView.contentOffset.y

        let newOffset = -1 * offsetY
        let newHeight = (height) + newOffset

        self.lastContentDifference =  height + newOffset

        if (self.lastContentOffset > 64) {
            navigationBarTransparency(transparent: true)
        } else {
            navigationBarTransparency(transparent: false)
        }

        self.lastContentOffset = self.lastContentDifference

        headerView?.headerImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: offsetY, width: tableView.frame.width, height: newHeight)
        headerView?.headerImage.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

This is the scrollViewdidScroll

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    isBouncing = scrollView.isBouncing

    if let tableView = scrollView as? UITableView {
        updateHeaderView()

        for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
            guard let cell = cell as? ArticleDetailPost else { continue }
            cell.webView.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

}
```

This is inside my viewDidLoad

```
        tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .grouped)
    tableView.backgroundColor = .white
    tableView.register(ArticleDetailHeader.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: headerId)
    tableView.register(ArticleDetailPost.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    tableView.separatorColor = .clear        
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-64, 0, -40, 0)
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
    tableView.backgroundColor = .green
```

I have a feeling I'm overlooking something very simple, but it's been breaking my brain for the past few hours.

Comment: try setting the table view content inset to never from storyboard. Or if you want to do through code then
`if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}`

Comment: I'll try to mess with this a bit, however, it's not the exact solution. Maybe through a work around I can get this to work.

Comment: do u got solution ?